# Tkinter how to place image into a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen other posts about this topic but they are not very conclusive, they only provide a suggestion to use other modules to do this.

I am trying to insert my `maincharacter.png`(http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-character--600.png) image into my `top_left` frame.

Code (run it):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class GameScreen:
    def __init__(self, master):

        # create all of the main containers
        top_left = Frame(master, bg='black', width=200, height=200)
        top_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        top_right = Frame(master, bg="green", width=200, height=200)
        middle_left = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_left = Frame(master, bg='green',width=200, height=200 )
        bottom_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200 )
        bottom_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)

        # layout all of the main containers
        top_left.grid(row=0)
        top_middle.grid(row=0, column = 1)
        top_right.grid(row=0, column=2)
        middle_left.grid(row=1)
        middle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        middle_right.grid(row=1, column=2)
        bottom_left.grid(row=2)
        bottom_middle.grid(row=2, column=1)
        bottom_right.grid(row=2, column=2)

        c1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('maincharacter.png'))
        c1_label = Label(top_left, image=c1)
        c1_label.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("RPG Game")
root.geometry("600x600")
display = GameScreen(root)



root.mainloop()
```

When I tried to do this, there were mainly two problems:

- All my frames moved out of place
- My character might be too big

Edit - why are there white lines now:

[image: GUI]

Comment: I haven't really worked with images in tkinter, but I think you're supposed to plot them to a canvas similar to matplotlib plots? I think that this may solve your frames moving out of place problem, because the canvas is placed inside a frame that has set properties.

Comment: I think you use canvas objects when plotting graphics, although I myself am not massively experienced with tkinter either :/... Here's a link to a picture viewer somebody made. It could be useful to you perhaps? They define a class `class PictureWindow(Tkinter.Canvas)` in their "GUI.py" so maybe you could try something similar? http://www.bitforestinfo.com/2017/02/how-to-create-image-viewer-using-python.html

Comment: In order to run your code as is, we need the `maincharacter.png` file. Please [edit] your question and add it or a link to it.

Comment: *"My character might be too big"*: Yes, resize to frame size `200x200`. If you don't want your frames to autoresize, use `<frame>.propagate(0)`

Comment: stovfl I can only resize the image after knowing the method to display the image, I don't know if I have to use Canvas, Pillow or PhotoImage in this context and it doesn't seem like anything is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class GameScreen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # create all of the main containers
        top_left = Frame(master, bg='black', width=200, height=200)
        top_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        top_right = Frame(master, bg="green", width=200, height=200)
        middle_left = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_left = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)

        # layout all of the main containers
        top_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        top_middle.grid(row=0, column=1)
        top_right.grid(row=0, column=2)
        middle_left.grid(row=1, column=0)
        middle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        middle_right.grid(row=1, column=2)
        bottom_left.grid(row=2, column=0)
        bottom_middle.grid(row=2, column=1)
        bottom_right.grid(row=2, column=2)

        image = Image.open("maincharacter.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((196, 196), Image.ANTIALIAS))

        label = Label(top_left, image=photo, bg='green')
        label.image = photo
        label.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("RPG Game")
root.geometry("600x600")
display = GameScreen(root)

root.mainloop()
```

In my opinion this is a better option:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class GameScreen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # create all of the main containers
        top_left = Frame(master, bg='black', width=200, height=200)
        top_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        top_right = Frame(master, bg="green", width=200, height=200)
        middle_left = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        middle_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_left = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_middle = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)
        bottom_right = Frame(master, bg='green', width=200, height=200)

        # layout all of the main containers
        top_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        top_middle.grid(row=0, column=1)
        top_right.grid(row=0, column=2)
        middle_left.grid(row=1, column=0)
        middle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        middle_right.grid(row=1, column=2)
        bottom_left.grid(row=2, column=0)
        bottom_middle.grid(row=2, column=1)
        bottom_right.grid(row=2, column=2)

        # create a canvas to show image on
        canvas_for_image = Canvas(top_left, bg='green', height=200, width=200, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas_for_image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=0, pady=0)

        # create image from image location resize it to 200X200 and put in on canvas
        image = Image.open('maincharacter.png')
        canvas_for_image.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        canvas_for_image.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas_for_image.image, anchor='nw')

root = Tk()
root.title("RPG Game")
root.geometry("600x600")
display = GameScreen(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Partho63, I have made an edit to my post. Why are there now white lines?

Comment: @Newbie101 change `image.resize((200, 200)` to `image.resize((196, 196)` I have updated my solution's process one. check that.